# Installing Qt5 webenginewidgets module from Ubuntu repositories

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, qwebview, qwebengineview

I know I can install any Qt5 module using the Qt Maintenance Tool, which I used before. However, in the latest Ubuntu (18.04), I've stumbled upon a problem: my app uses QNetworkManager, and SSL-connections are now not working, apparently because Qt version I was using was built with another SSL version. I googled for this issue, and found that as a solution, it is advised to use "native" Qt install from online repositories. I did that, but now I cannot even `qmake` the project file, and the error is:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

(my app uses QWebView, so I have `QT += webenginewidgets` in the .pro-file).
Ok, I've made `sudo apt install` for everything I could find related to "webview/webengine" in Qt (`libqt5webengine5`, `libqt5webengine-data`, `libqt5webview5`, `libqt5webenginecore5`, `libqt5webenginewidgets5`, `libqt5webview5-dev`), but this made no any difference at all: still, unknown module in Qt.

So - how do I install Qt5 webenginwidgets module from repositories in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: So the answer is: `sudo apt install qtwebengine5-dev`.

Comment: You should submit this comment as your answer to your question and mark it as accepted. AFAIK that is ok so long as the question is useful and for me it was as I too was caught out by this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my system (Ubuntu 18.04) I solved the issue like that:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install libqt5webenginewidgets5
```